# How to write unit tests for Firestore pod Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a newbie in the unit test, and I'm struggling with the unit tests for a feature that uses a firebase library. I'm trying to test this part of the code

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

protocol ArtworksServiceProtocol {
     func fetchArtworkData(artworkID id: String, completionHandler: @escaping (ArtworkModel?, ArtworkError?) -> Void)
}

class ArtworksService: ArtworksServiceProtocol {

let db: Firestore!

init(db: Firestore = Firestore.firestore()) {
    self.db = db
}

func fetchArtworkData(artworkID id: String, completionHandler: @escaping (ArtworkModel?, ArtworkError?) -> Void) {
    let docRef = db.collection("Posts").document(id)
    docRef.getDocument(source: .server) { (document, _) in
        if let document = document {
            do {
                let result = try document.data(as: ArtworkModel.self)
                completionHandler(result, nil)
            } catch {
                completionHandler(nil, ArtworkError.parsingError)
            }
          } else {
            completionHandler(nil, ArtworkError.databaseError)
          }
      }
  }
}
```

How I can create a mock for db variable? I couldn't find any protocols to mock for Firestore class. How I can deal with this kind of problem with the unit tests?

Comment: You could break out the code in the closure and move it to a separate function that takes `document` and the completion handler as arguments and then mock `document` (whatever type that is, I haven't used Firestore much).

Comment: If you want to unit test, you have to mock external libraries, otherwise you will be just testing *them*. You should ask yourself first whether the test will be helpful or not.